# Old Mac Tank Game - Bolo

Tags: bolo

I really miss [Bolo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolo_%28video_game%29), haven't played it in over a decade.  Is this game still out there and can it still be played multiplayer?  I'd love to throw an old games LAN party that featured it.

Comment: I know the question says Mac, but what's funny is that the first thing it brought to mind was the Apple II game with the same name.

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis There's another game named 'bolo' that has nothing to do with tanks, too. :) I forget what platform...

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I've been trying to remember this game for weeks now! I didn't post on here because all I could remember was, "some tank game when I was in college"

Comment: @Torpesh Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page you linked, "Mac OS X" is one of the platforms it can be played on.  Multiplayer requires AppleTalk, which means [OSX 10.6 and above can't be used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleTalk).

[There are also Windows and Linux clones](http://www.winbolo.com/).

Comment: I also noticed that the wiki's screenshot was for 'winbolo' which gave me hope that it was ready for non-appletalk LAN. I'm guessing you're input here is: "That's not very likely."

Comment: @qoonpooka Winbolo appears to be an unofficial clone, so it's doubtful that the original has been updated.  There's also [XBolo](http://xbolo.org/bolo/) but I don't think it supports multiplayer yet.

Comment: The windows and linux clones are client/server, which suggests net play and both claim active matching websites. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[nuBolo](http://web.archive.org/web/20130128024542/http://www.nubolo.net:80/) can be used natively on modern Mac machines. It actually contains code from the original Bolo so it's a perfect clone, unlike the win or linux variants.

If you're still aiming to run it under another system with networking, I would bet on running Bolo in an emulated System 7 image. You can do this pretty easily with [Basilisk II](http://emaculation.com/doku.php/basilisk_ii_setup) (great for running all sorts of System 7-era games, btw). There's also a Basilisk for osx if you end up going that route and want to network between windows/osx machines. nuBolo is likely incompatibile with the original.

Comment: Sadly Apple dropped PowerPC emulation in Lion (10.7), so it looks like nuBolo is dead.

Comment: Today (April 2017) nuBolo.net redirected to a malicious site.  I'll fix this answer, and do some digging.

Comment: I'm delighted to report that today, Sunday 16 April 2017, I've downloaded the Bolo disk image from the above Wayback Machine archive of the website, installed it on my Power Mac G5, and started to play.  Woohoo!